# How to pass Firebase DataSnapshot to Java's List?

Tags: java, android

Here's Basically what I want to do: Im trying to fill an Object List to use with a Recycler View:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

               list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Some.class));

}
```

The RecyclerView Does not shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try add notifyDataSetChanged() on code.
Example:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
      list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Some.class));
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```